# Set Cookie with a URL keyword

Tags: url, cookies, keyword

I have a URL where I am passing in a keyword (http://www.example.com/store?keyword=google). I want to set a cookie with the value of that keyword (cookie value will be google)...

Can this be done? Can anyone put me on the right track, I know how to set cookies, just dont know how to pull a keyword out of the URL to do it.

Thanks!

PS I am using PHP

Comment: What language are you working with? PHP?

Comment: It would help to know what you plan to use to set the cookie: javascript? asp? php? python? perl? etc. etc.

Comment: sorry guys, long day today, I am using PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't mentioned the language you are using, assuming if it's php -

The basic syntax for setting a cookie in php is -
    setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain);

So, for value you can get it as

```
 $value = $_GET['keyword'];
```

or you can also use

```
 $value = $_REQUEST['keyword'];
```

Now, $value variable holds the cookie value (in this case 'google') so you just need to pass it as-

```
<?php
setcookie("user", "$value", time()+3600);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not using server side code. If that is the case, I suggest you to read this short tutorial on Javascript and cookies from w3schools:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Sorry I am using PHP, should have said that, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

To pull a keyword, you can use the document.location.search to pull the complete ?keyword=google string. Now you can use regex to find the value of the keyword.

Code will look like:

```
var keyword = document.location.search.match(/\?keyword=(.*)/i)[1]
```

then you can create a cookie using JS with that value.